# Java сумма четных максимальных элементов в массиве и минимальных

Tags: java, массивы, классы

Всем привет. У меня задание создать двумерный массив ее транспонировать, а также вычислить сумму наибольших элементов в столбцах матрицы с парными номерами и наименьшими элементами в столбцах матрицы с непарными номерами. Собственно я все реализовал, но сумма парных у меня не получается, вывод не тот. Я решил посмотреть, реализация у многих та же но не работает. У меня проблема непосредственно с методом `find_big()` Помогите разобраться. Заранее благодарен.

Вот весь код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Massiv {
    private double[][] mass;
    private int size_mass_n, size_mass_m;private String sier;

public void worker() {

    System.out.println("Enter size for n: ");
    Scanner input_mass = new Scanner(System.in);
    sier = input_mass.nextLine();
    size_mass_n = Integer.parseInt(sier);

    System.out.println("Enter size for m: ");
    input_mass = new Scanner(System.in);
    sier = input_mass.nextLine();
    size_mass_m = Integer.parseInt(sier);

    mass = new double[size_mass_n][size_mass_m];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_mass_n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size_mass_m; j++) {
            mass[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 256);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size_mass_n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size_mass_m; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + mass[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public void find_big() {
    //double sum_chetn = 0; double sum_nechetn = 0;
    double max = mass[0][0], min = mass[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i < mass[0].length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mass.length; j++) {
            if(mass[j][i] % 2 == 0) {
                if(max < mass[j][i]) {
                    max += mass[j][i];
                    System.out.println("Sum max chetn " + max);
                }
            }
            else if(mass[j][i] % 2 != 0) {
                if(min > mass[j][i]) {
                    min += mass[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum max chetn " + max);
    System.out.println("Sum min nechetn " + min);
}

public void transpons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mass[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (mass.length); j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + mass[j][i]);
        }System.out.println();
     }
  }
}

public class Laba2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.

        Massiv mass = new Massiv();
        mass.worker();
        mass.find_big();
        mass.transpons();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `find_big()` действительно работает не так. Когда он находит новый максимальный элемент, ему всё-равно, был ли в той же строке (столбце) другой. Таким образом, отдельная строчка `"1 2 3 4"` выдаст сумму `"10"`, а `"4 3 2 1"` - `"4"`.

Вам следует в первом вложенном цикле завести переменную для текущего максимума строчки и внутри второго её обновлять. Только после полного обхода строчки - суммировать. Та же история, конечно, и с минимумами. Код циклов:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
    double cmax = max;
    double cmin = min;
    for(int j = 0; j < mass[0].length; j++) {
        if(j % 2 == 1) {
            if(cmax < mass[i][j]) {
                cmax = mass[i][j];
            }
        }
        else if(j % 2 != 1) {
            if(cmin > mass[i][j]) {
                cmin = mass[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    sum_max += cmax;
    System.out.println("Sum max chetn " + sum_max);
    sum_min += cmin;
}
```

Однако у вас ещё 3 недочёта, исправленных выше:

1. Циклы имеют неправильное кол-во итераций, стоит сделать для первого цикла `mass.length`, а для второго `mass[0].length`.
2. Вы сравниваете текущую сумму `max` с `mass[i][j]`, а не найденный максимум строки
3. Вы проверяете четность не индекса столбца, в значение самой ячейки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73747/discussion-on-answer-by-dmig-java------).